# Highlight columns in Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

I use Sublime Text 3, Build 3103. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21288455/5951529) it is written that highlights of columns is entered into Build 3080, but I see nothing.

[image: Highlights column]

Plugin [GoCowRol](https://github.com/bstidham/sublimetext2-GotoRowCol) for Sublime Text 2, not Sublime Text 3. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by highlight columns? The command `:5:20` repositions the caret to line 5 in front of character 20 (if you hit enter after typing the command). This is actually a built in feature since 3080 and works also in 3103 (tested).

Comment: @Peh, I apologize, I didn't know that columns aren't highlighted, and the caret draws near them. But my caret doesn't draw in front of character 20 of a line 5 but only the line is highlighted. Thanks.

Comment: Make sure that line 5 has at least 20 characters. If there are less then the caret jumps over to the next line. And make sure you confirm the command by pressing `enter`. The line is already selected on the fly while you are typing but for the column you need to confirm with `enter`.

Comment: @Peh, thank you very much, I didn't think that `Enter` should press. Please, make the your comment as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command `:5:20` *repositions* the caret to line 5 in front of character 20 (there is no highlighting). This is actually a built in feature since 3080 and works also in 3103 (tested).

- Make sure that line 5 has at least 20 characters. If there are less then the caret jumps over to the next line.
- And make sure you confirm the command by pressing <kbd>enter</kbd>. The line is already selected *on the fly* while typing, but for the column you need to confirm with <kbd>enter</kbd>.